# Regex Find substrings between brackets tags

Tags: regex, tags, text-parsing

I need a regular expression to select text between two outer tags. The tags are ugly brackets tags and the start tag looks like the stop tag.

The start tag (and the 3 substrings) are followed by CR LF

The substrings are separeted with horizontal tabs

Example:

```
    (Text)
    Subtext1    Subtext2    Subtext3
    (Text)
```

Result:
Subtext1,Subtext2,Subtext3

Answer (score 0):

Regex by its self is not going to return the results you are looking for. 
You need some language or tool that will leverage the regex to pull out the parts you seek.
As such, the solution is VERY dependent on the tool or language you choose to use so without knowing what tool that may be, it is really impossible to give a good answer.

That being said, this may or may not be useful depending on the tool leveraging the regex:
((.+)\n((.*)\t?)+(.*))